# Why to use where clause even when Having can be used for the same purpose?

Tags: sql, performance-testing

It is known that Having clause works same as where clause but where clause only works with present table columns and not aggregate columns.

Can we always use *Having* and is there some specific functionality which where is preferable than having, like performance issues?

Comment: The standard SQL dictates that you can use `HAVING` only in presence of a `GROUP BY` clause, which is not always present in every query.

Answer (score 1):

The only instance I have ever seen where (no pun intended) `WHERE` and `HAVING` could possibly be used interchangably is with the MySQL database, and for certain situations.

In a MySQL query which does *not* have a `GROUP BY` clause, `HAVING` would appear to do the same thing which `WHERE` does.  Consider the following query:

```
SELECT (a + b + c) / (d + e) AS some_computed_column
FROM yourTable
WHERE some_computed_column = 10    -- WRONG!
```

In the above query, we tried to use a computed column alias in the `WHERE` clause, but did not get away with it.  The reason for this is that MySQL cannot guarantee that the alias will be available at the time the `WHERE` clause is evaluated.  This would appear to leave us with only the following option:

```
SELECT (a + b + c) / (d + e) AS some_computed_column
FROM yourTable
WHERE (a + b + c) / (d + e) = 10    -- correct, but ugly
```

The above query is correct, will run, but is ugly and possibly verbose, because we had to repeat the logic of the computed column again.  However, it *is* possible to use the `HAVING` clause as an alternative, as the alias will be available at that point in the query.  Hence, we could write the following:

```
SELECT (a + b + c) / (d + e) AS some_computed_column
FROM yourTable
HAVING some_computed_column = 10    -- allowed, and not ugly
```

But keep in mind that not every database will accept the above query.  If you want a database independent way of avoiding the verbosity, you could wrap the original query in a subquery, and then query that, e.g.:

```
SELECT t.some_computed_column
FROM
(
    SELECT (a + b + c) / (d + e) AS some_computed_column
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.some_computed_column = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

They reflect two different steps the dbms will do when executing a query. Take this example:

```
select  person_id, count(distinct child_id)
from    parenthood
where   child_age > 6
group by person_id
having  count(distinct child_id) > 1
```

What you need to do is

1. filtering the total rows
2. aggregating the remaining rows
3. filtering the resulting groups

Writing that query like

```
select  person_id, count(distinct child_id)
from    parenthood
group by person_id
having  child_age > 6 and count(distinct child_id) > 1
```

wouldn't change the steps the dbms would do, and would make the query a bit harder to understand.

In fact, while latest versions of MySQL allow some creative combinatinos of `group by`, aggregation functions and `having`, most dbms expect you to use `having` only in combination with `group by`, and only applied to aggregation functions, and will return an error otherwise.